How to refresh Entity Framework Core DbContext of ASP.NET Core project when connection string in web.config is changed?
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 project with Entity Framework Core. The connection string is taken from web.config in the root folder. While debugging in Visual Studio 2022, I enabled Hot Reload. I have figured out way to refresh DbContext when hot reload is triggered.
I use this code:
[assembly: System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataUpdateHandler(typeof(HotReloadManager))]
namespace xxx
{
    internal static class HotReloadManager
    {
        public static void ClearCache(Type[]? types)
        {
            // Clear any caches if needed
        }

        public static void UpdateApplication(Type[]? types)
        { 
            using var context = new xxxDbContext();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
    }
}

It works fine while hot reloading. DbContext is refreshed. Then the next thing is when I edit connection string in web.config, I find that this will not trigger hot reload. How can I achieve that?

ASP.NET Core typically doesn't use web.config - but appsettings.json instead ...

It can use web.config but not as popular as appsettings.json.

Why is this a problem you're trying to solve? You won't hot reload the site in a production context, nor edit the config settings on the fly and need the app to instantly see the change and trigger off them

While in development in ViusalStudio, I may switch connectiong string sometimes. Then I have to restart the program, which takes time. So, I am thinking if it can trigger hot reload when I edit config file, it will be easy.

Normally web.config is used with IIS hosting and changes to the file would trigger the site to refresh, dumping current sessions. If you want to use ASP.Net Core and have the site construct DbContext instances with a config file setting at the time of request then consider a DbContextFactory so that any instance created pulls the connection string from the desired config file each time.

Hi @StevePy, when every DbContext is created, it uses a static property. public static string? ConnectionString => ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ConnectionString;. It seems that it does not refresh value from config file when every DbContext is created.

ConfigurationManager will read the config on the first request and continue to return that cached data each request.  You might be able to mark the connection strings to reload on next request using ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("ConnectionStrings") but otherwise you should consider instantiating a new config using OpenMappedExeConfiguration() rather than the static ConnectionStrings helper.

@StevePy, Good. Thanks!

Have you tried using IOptions? Specifically IOptionsMonitor or IOptionsSnapshot. See below for additional info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-9.0#options-interfaces
https://edi.wang/post/2019/1/5/auto-refresh-settings-changes-in-aspnet-core-runtime

IOptionsMonitor has an OnChange method that will be called when the underlying configuration source changes. Or you can use IOptionsSnapshot which might be better if DbContext is a scoped/transient service.
This way you can also omit the HotReloadManager part.
